# how to reset all the grid view text to null

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a tic tac toe game. I have constructed the grid and it alternate between x and o for two player to begin there game. I have also made the conditions and the logic of the game , but I got a problem while resetting the cells to a `null` one to begin a new game. The problem that using `GestureDetector` it use the index of the last clicked cell and reset it, while I want to reset the whole grid. what should I do ??

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _changelett(_choice); //alternate between X and O turns
            _changeCell(widget.index); //Write to cell
            _checkWinner(); 
          },
          child: new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: cellColor,
            ),
            child: new Center(
              child: cellText,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: I would like to know some more code for answering. Can you show `_checkWinner` logic?

Comment: `_checkWinner(){
    setState(() {
         if(var0==var1 && var1==var2){
               if (var0=='X'){
               xscore++ ;
              _resetchange();
    //was trying to reset the values of the grid cell again 
  runApp(new MaterialApp( home: new DemoScreen(),)); 
  }
  else if (var0=='O'){
    oscore++;
    runApp(new MaterialApp( home: new DemoScreen(),)); 
}
}`

Comment: this is the first case where cell0 , cell1 , and cell2  got X as an input , so the user 'X' wins therefore I want to start another game a increase the score for the x player. The problem what I got here is  resting the whole grid cell . even I restated the value of the cell text and the cell color. it only changes the triggered cell not the whole cells